# Regex for matching all image links except the ones followed by the text " (deleted)" without quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match all image links (`.jpg` or `.png`) in a block of text except the ones where it is followed by `(deleted)` without quotes.  For example, consider the following block of text:

> lorem ipsum
>
> https://photos.google.com/asdfasd/image1.png
>
> https://photos.google.com/jpg/image2.jpg
>
> lorem ipsum hasdf
>
> https://photos.google.com/asdfasd/image3.png (deleted)
>
> https://photos.google.com/pngsdfasd/image4.jpg Done
>
> asdfasdf

In the above text, the links for `Image 1`, `Image 2` and `Image 4` should be flagged but `Image 3` should not. Please note that there is a space between the link and `(deleted)`.

Here is my regex for matching the links:

```
/http[^\s]+(jpg|png)/gm
```

I am trying to do this in JavaScript (Node).  Link to the example on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3u29m).

Comment: Simply use a [negative lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-look-ahead): `http[^\s]+(jpg|png)(?! \(deleted\))`

Comment: `/http[^\s]+(?:jpg|png)(?! \(deleted\))/gm`?

Comment: Thanks, Hamms and CAustin. It works great!